# In Star Wars legends, when did Luke officially recognize himself as a Jedi Master?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I know Luke was a Jedi Knight after *Return of the Jedi*, but in what novel, comic or game did he recognize himself as a Master?

Comment: According to wookiepedia, he gained the title in 11 ABY. But I couldn't find exactly what caused him to declare that nor what EU medium it was in.

Comment: He's the only Jedi left, isn't he? So, by definition he's a master relative to the whole population of Jedi.

Comment: Well he claimed to be one in jabbas palace...

Comment: The newer answer by @Omegacron should be the accepted one

Comment: @Chad *"I am Luke Skywalker, Jedi Knight and friend to captain Solo."*

Comment: Retconed...  In the original ROTJ he claimed to be a jedi master

Comment: @Chad - Harmy's is the only *original* that I know exists, and that's where I got the quote. I'm very interested in your source for the *theatrical release* of RotJ, claiming to the contrary.

Comment: I watched in 1983 in the movie theater... and I remember at the time thinking that was a bold claim for someone who never even finished his apprentice training with Yoda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, it happened between *Heir to the Empire* series and the *Jedi Academy* series, with no specific EU coverage of it. He was supposed to be recognized as one by the Council, but since there was no council, he had no choice but to recognize himself as Master prior to training apprentices at the Academy.

Comment: The Dark Empire Trilogy (which I haven't read for years) comes between those two, did it happen there?

Comment: @NikolaiDante - I don't recall, don't have access to the books to confrirm ATM, and never saw any info to indicate so. But i'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 27):

Luke Skywalker was officially recognized as a Jedi Master in 11 ABY. His sister Leia recommended he take the title while discussing his plans for a new Jedi Praxeum. Luke mulled this over while searching for Force-sensitive individuals in the novel [**Jedi Search**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Search), but officially took the title when establishing his new academy on Yavin IV. Here's the quote where he accepted the title himself:

> Inside, his heart seemed a diamond-hard lump. He wasn't merely another
>   Jedi Knight -- he was the only remaining Jedi Master. He had survived
>   tests and rigors more potent than routine Jedi training prepared him
>   for. Luke understood more about the Force now than he had ever dreamed
>   possible. Sometimes it terrified him.

As for why, the logic was that if he was taking the role of a teacher - indeed, the leader - within the New Jedi Order, he should no longer consider himself a simple "Jedi Knight". His new title was officially active as of the novel [**Dark Apprentice**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Apprentice_(novel)). It still took some getting used to for the humble Luke, as evidenced by his reaction the first time a student calls him "Master":

> "Show me your new Jedi exercises, Master. Teach me other things."
>   Skywalker seemed to flinch at being called 'Master', and Gantoris
>   wondered what he had done wrong -- was not Luke Skywalker a Jedi Master?
>   How else should he be called?

As of those events in 11 ABY, he was not only recognized as <strike>a</strike> *THE* Jedi Master by his students, but also by Mon Mothma and the New Republic Ruling Council. Even after most of his original students had attained the rank of Jedi Master, Luke was considered the unofficial leader of the Order.

Years later, during the Killik Crisis, Luke was forced to take the title "Grand Master of the Jedi Order", largely to provide the faltering Jedi Order with leadership following several heated disputes among the Jedi Masters. His leadership role was somewhat reduced after he re-formed the Jedi Council, although he retained the Grand Master title for the rest of the Legends continuity.

Comment: Add a couple of quotes and I'll officially lobby for this to change to accepted answer :)  +1 either way - good find!

Comment: @DVK - don't have access to the books right now, but I've added a couple of quotes I could find.